# How to read all files in the reverse direction

Tags: vim

I do vim *.java to read files in a certain directory. How do I traverse in the reverse direction after opening these files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could:

```
vim `ls *.java | tac`
```

(This is assuming you have `tac` available from GNU coreutils. It reverses all the lines of its input.)

Answer (score 1):

Editing the files listed in the argument list (see `:help arglist`) in the
reverse order is pretty much the same as in the natural one.

1. Jump to the last file in the list.

   ```
   :last
   ```
2. Iteratively switch from a file to the one preceding it in the list.

   ```
   :N
   ```